# httpPost url to post app data

Tags: php, android, mysql

I want to send my data directly from my mobile to MySQL database.I used php to connect to MySQL.But in android code I can't get which url is passing inside httppost.
My code is.

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("127.0.0.1/connect.php");
                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

which path is to set under this httppost?

suggest please!
Also my php code is-:

```
<?php
$icon = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if(!$icon)
{
    die('Could not connect : ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("password", $icon)or die("database selection error");
echo json_encode($data);
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
$id=$_POST['id'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO signup_db (firstname, lastname, id, phone, password)
VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$id', '$phone', '$password')",$icon);
mysql_close($icon);
?>
```

Comment: what is the field name to be send

Comment: its just a form-:(fname,lname,emailid,phoneNo)

Comment: you need to send it as namevalue pairs Httppost sends data as associative array

Comment: I have done it and it is in correct manner.when I used above code to executing httppost to send data(in try/catch),flow always move in catch block.

Comment: I think the url I have taken inside httppost is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private EditText name, email, mobile, password;
private Button btn;
private ProgressBar pb;
String name1, email1, mobile1, password1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);
    pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    name1 = name.getText().toString();
    email1 = email.getText().toString();
    mobile1 = mobile.getText().toString();
    password1 = password.getText().toString();
    int success = 1;// for avoiding pressing invalid parameters to website
    if (name1.length() < 1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "PLEASE ENTER NAME", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        success = 0;
    }

    if (email1.length() < 1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "PLEASE PROVIDE EMAIL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        success = 0;
    }
    if (mobile1.length() < 10) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MOBILE NUMBERS MUST BE 10 DIGITS LONG",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        success = 0;
    }
    if (password1.length() < 6) {

        // out of range
        Toast.makeText(this, "PLEASE PROVIDE ATLEAST 6 DIGITS PASSWORD",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        success = 0;
    }
    if (success == 1) {
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(name.getText().toString());

    }

}

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double> {

    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        postData(name1, email1, password1, mobile1);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Double result) {
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Account Activated Login To MyGenie", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,
                LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    public void postData(String name, String email, String password,
            String mobile) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "http://www.mygenie.me/json/json.php");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            nameValuePairs
                    .add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", mobile));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: sir I have done a bit same but can't understand which path of url is taken under httppost

Comment: none of the path of url is taken the data is sent to url as an associative array which is sort of hidden

Comment: this code works for me i need to see your php code for more information on what you need to do for the time being check new BasicNameValuePair("name", name) here "name" should me matching to your table fields in database

Comment: use my code and add new id field in BasicNameValuePairs and change your url to http://127.0.0.1/connect.php I guess this will work but make sure your php code can be used from browser

Answer (score 0):

you can see here .what you want exactly [Send Data to server from android](http://adilmukarram.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/sending-and-receiving-data-from-a-php-web-application/)

Comment: my php file is in easyphp->www->new folder->connect.php.then what should be the url?

Comment: php file in live server or localhost ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42191/discussion-between-karthi-and-barun)